# Theme Customizier sanitize_callback not working

Tags: theme-options, theme-customizer, sanitization

I have a theme option to set the slider speed. The `sanitize_callback` function is not working. I would like the function to set the speed to 4000ms if a non numeric character is entered.

```
function slider_speed_sanitize($input) {
    if (!is_positive_integer($input)) {
        $input = 4000;
    }
    return $input;
}

function is_positive_integer($str) {
    return (is_numeric($str) && $str > 0 && $str == round($str));
}
```

When I enter non numeric characters, it sets the speed to 0.

Comment: There is no such function like `is_positive_integer()` in Wordpress. If you really need this answered, we need to see the code for `is_positive_integer()` as it seems like this is where your code fails

Comment: I added the code for is_positive_integer() @PieterGoosen